# Concurrency : Designing a REST API using Play Framework/Akka

Tags: java, rest, concurrency, playframework-2.0, akka

I m relatively new to Play framework. I'm trying to design a "Test/Quiz/Exam" app. It mostly consist of few CRUD operations on multiple tables (Right Now). Its has a 
REST based Back end -- > AngularJS frontend.

Lets say for the GET request of format /users/{id} the following code is mapped

```
public Result getUser(Long id)  {
    // Get Info from DB using Spring Data JPA and return result.
}
```

Now as I came across Akka Actor model, is it better to re-write the getUser function such that it delegates the work to an Actor which retrieves the data from the DB and returns it. Should i follow actor model for rest of the CRUD operations too ?. Or is it an overkill to user Akka here (assuming the Play takes care of the concurrency for each request). FYI I just started looking into Akka.

Design tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's overkill to use Akka here, because Play handles the inter-request concurrency and from your description of the problem it doesn't appear that you have any intra-request concurrency (which is where you'd use Akka, e.g. if you were making a thousand independent database queries then you could distribute these across a dozen actors or something along those lines).  If you just want to make the Play actions asynchronous then see the [JavaAsync](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.4/JavaAsync) documentation.

Comment: when you mean a "thousand db queries" do you mean a 1000 queries per request or 1000 request each making a db query ?

Comment: And given my scenario should i make my play actions asynchronous ?

Comment: AbrahamDaniel: Play actions are actually asynchronous by default. "Whether the action code returns a Result or a Promise<Result>, both kinds of returned object are handled internally in the same way. There is a single kind of Action, which is asynchronous, and not two kinds (a synchronous one and an asynchronous one)." See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaAsync

Comment: @AbrahamDaniel I mean a single request making 1000 queries; a thousand requests each making a single query gets handled well enough by Play, and it's unnecessary to complicate things with Akka